# How to access data from a data class in another data class?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I've two data class as follows:

```
data class Resource(
    val location: String,
    val address: String
)

data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    var userName: String,
    var screenName: String,
    var email: String,
    var place: Resource,
    var register: Instant,
    val timezone: TimeZone
)
```

I want to call the class **resource** inside the class **Student**.

Here Student is my in-memory database.
Following code fills the database with dummy data when the application launches.

```
@Component
class StudentDatabase {

    private val students = mutableListOf<Student>()
    //Following annotation shows a filled database when application launches
    @PostConstruct
    private fun init(){
        val placedata1: Boolean = resource.add(Resource("gf","fhf,67"))
        val placedata2: Boolean = resource.add(Resource("gf","fhf,67"))

        students.add(Student(35446,"James12","qwerty","Jamesd@icloud.com", placedata1, Instant.now(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")))
        students.add(Student(46666,"Thomas3556","srdg54","thomas12@gmail.com", placedata2, Instant.now(),TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "I want to add some details to 'resource' so that I can get the same in 'Student'"?

Comment: I want the data in class 'Resource' inside the class 'Student'.

Comment: You mean like foreignKeys?

Comment: yes @SaeedEntezari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Resource properties in Student class. You can do it straight away. They are public by default.

```
data class Resource(
    val location: String,
    val address: String
)

data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    var userName: String,
    var screenName: String,
    var email: String,
    var place: Resource,
    val location: String = place.location
)
```

or if you want to access it in method and manipulate,

```
data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    var userName: String,
    var screenName: String,
    var email: String,
    var place: Resource,
    val location: String = place.location
) {
    fun getLocationLowerCase():String {
        return place.location.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```